# Detect browser focus/out-of-focus via Google Chrome Extension

Tags: browser, google-chrome, focus, window

Is there a way to find out if Google chrome is in focus or out of focus? I'm creating an app which needs to know if the user is currently using the browser or not.

By tying the detection through the content script in a Google extension, I've tried using blur and focus but the problem is that clicking on the address bar also fires a blur event. Same goes for detecting mouse movement, where moving the mouse outside of the viewing area will not be detected.

I've also tried looking at onFocusChanged but it seems it only detects changes in chromes' windows not apps outside of Chrome.

Anyone have other ideas for this? Also, would this be any easier if I created an add-on for firefox instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the answer? chrome.window.onFocusChanged doesn't seem to be working

Comment: onFocusChanged now works for detecting Chrome losing focus entirely: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#event-onFocusChanged

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `chrome.windows` API to monitor this.  You would add a listener for the `onFocusChanged` event and if the event returned `-1` or `chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE` then you know that the browser lost focus:

```
var inFocus = true;  // global boolean to keep track of state
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(window) {
    if (window == chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE) {
        inFocus = false;
    } else {
        inFocus = true;
    }
});
```

[Chrome.Window Doc](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#event-onFocusChanged)

Comment: As it was mentioned in the question itself, onFocusChanged isn't triggered when user navigates to different application, it only works when user navigates between different chrome windows. This means that it is not a working solution.
The only approach I have found so far is to query getCurrent in intervals every once in a while and check its focused property which is false even on current window when different application is in focus.
(This is tested on chrome 39 canary, windows 8)

Comment: Also draft has been proposed a while ago with which we could get information in which state is window, however I do not know if something more has been done.

https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/window-management

One really useful extension could be done then, like page refresh on focused window. This would be really nice feature for web developers.

Comment: _...onFocusChanged isn't triggered when user navigates to different application..._  

Not true for me. This method for focus detection works. When I switch to a different application from Chrome then `inFocus` becomes `false` and vice versa. And this is much better than `setTimeout()` (Tested on Chrome 76.0.3809.132 MacOS 10.13.6)

Comment: is @Giedrius's comment still true in 2020 for modern versions of Chrome?

Comment: @DmitryDavydov not working in Chrome 90.0.4430.93, Linux. It fires sometimes, but not if you alt-tab from Chrome to a non-Chrome window

Comment: @Salami how did you test it. This is from the doc "Note: On some Linux window managers, WINDOW_ID_NONE is always sent immediately preceding a switch from one Chrome window to another." . https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#event-onFocusChanged
Could be the way your are checking it?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe some don't see @Giedrius' comment. This interval works:

```
window.setInterval(checkBrowserFocus, 1000);  

function checkBrowserFocus(){

    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(browser){

      console.log(browser.focused)

    })

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
setInterval(function() {
    chrome.windows.getLastFocused(function(window) {
        console.log(window.id.toString() + "  " + window.focused.toString())
    });
}, 1000);
```

or：

```
setInterval(function() {
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(window) {
        console.log(window.id.toString() + "  " + window.focused.toString())
    });
}, 1000);
```

window.focused is false means that no chrome window is focused.

reference：https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is done by manipulating the blur and focus event.
Like this example in jQuery:

```
$(window).blur(function(){
    // do something when it loose focus like that:
    alert('Good Bye.');
});

$(window).focus(function(){
    // do something when it gains focus
    alert('Welcome back.');
});
```